# Simple CSS Float Issue

Tags: html, css

I am a beginner and I am trying to create something like this

[image]

But I am having trouble getting the lines to stack on top of each other to the left of the text.

Can someone help nudge me in the right direction here?

```css
#topbar {
 width: 15%;
 background-color: #000000;
 height: 3px;
 float: left;
}
#bottombar {
 width: 15%;
 background-color: #000000;
 height: 1px;
 float: none;
    clear: both;
}
#LocationText {
 float: left;
    font-size: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div id="topbar"></div>
<div id="LocationText">Location</div>
<div id="bottombar"></div>
```

here is my http://jsfiddle.net/y0sv7shs/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `::before` and `::after` :pseudo-elements.

```css
span {
  position: relative;
  margin-left: 100px;
  font-size: 50px;
}
span::before, span::after {
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
  border-top: 1px solid black;
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
  right: -50%;
  top: 0;
}
span::before {
  left: -50%;
}
```

```html
<span>Location</span>
```

---

Or you could do something like this:

```css
span {
  position: relative;
  margin-left: 100px;
  font-size: 50px;
}
span::before, span::after {
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  width: 50%;
  height: 25%;
  border-top: 2px solid black;
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
  right: -50%;
  top: 37.5%;
}
span::before {
  left: -50%;
}
```

```html
<span>Location</span>
```

---

The one that you requested.

[image]

```css
span {
  position: relative;
  font-family: 'Bree Serif', serif;
  margin-left: 100px;
  font-size: 50px;
  color: #A0001F;
  font-weight: bold;
}
span::before, span::after {
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  width: 100%;
  height: 15%;
  border-top: 2px solid #A0001F;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #A0001F;
  right: -100%;
  top: 42.5%;
}
span::before {
  left: -45%;
  width: 45%;
}
```

```html
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Bree+Serif' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<span>CONTACT</span>
```

Answer (score 1):

In addition to chipChocolate's answer, you may also contain the elements so as to force them to reside above one another in a particular location relative to the text (However, this would take more elements, and isn't as clean):

```
<div class="locationcontainer">
    <div id="topbar"></div>
    <div id="bottombar"></div>
</div>
<div id="LocationText">Location</div>

#topbar {
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #000000;
    height: 2px;
}
#bottombar {
    width:90%;
    background-color: #000000;
    height: 2px;
    margin-top: 10px;
    float:right;
}
.locationcontainer
{
    float:left;
    width:15%;
    margin-right:5px;
}
#LocationText {
    float: left;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/fstqdxeu/

Comment: How would I go about making the lines extend further on one side or the other?